# How can we get the Exact java business code from the TBO deployed in Documentum?

Tags: documentum

Currently we need to customize one of the existing TBO to add some functionality. However we are unable to find the exact code of TBO which we deployed last time.
Is there any way we can get it back from repository itself?

Usually we convert our Code to a single Jar file and add that to jardef. And we deploy the Dar file to Documentum repository. So is there a way to retrieve that Jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Navigate to

```
System/Modules/TBO/<your TBO name>
```

There should be jardef under `dmc_jar` object type. 
You can also query for `dmc_module` or `dmc_jar` to find them all, though I think all should be under *TBO* folder level.